# How to create Map<String,List<String>> in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting, map

How to create `Map<String,List<String>>` in Javascript?
Push method does not seem to work if we define

```
aMap = {} and 
if(aMap [key])
{                                      
    aMap[key].push(value);//this is not working for some reason
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create the key as an array, first.

```
// Create an empty Object
var aMap = {};
function addValueToKey(key, value) {
    // Shorcut || returns left side if it is "truthy," or the right otherwise.
    // This means that we only assign a new Array to the Object's property
    // if it has not previously been used.
    aMap[key] = aMap[key] || [];
    // Adds a value to the end of the Array
    aMap[key].push(value);
}
```

---

Once browsers support the new logical nullish assignment, we can write the code more gracefully (this will apply to LWC only):

```
var aMap = {};
function addValueToKey(key, value) {
  aMap[key] ??= [];
  aMap[key].push(value);
}
```

Where `??=` reads "Assign the value on the right to the left, only if the left is null/undefined", and will become the new standard for `someVar[key] = someVar[key] || newValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This worked for me.                                                         var arr = [];
arr.push(aMap[key]);
arr.push(value);
aMap[key]=arr;

Comment: @SyedAmberIqbal You're adding null to the array, then adding the value, then finally putting it into the named slot. That's not correct. A "map" in JS is {}, and an "array" is []. Start from the function above. And, FYI, this really should have been on Stack Overflow, so it'll probably be moved anways.

Comment: Yeah that's right this should be the correct part of the code               if(aMap[key])
{  
var arr = [];
arr.push(aMap[key]);
arr.push(value);                                                                         aMap[key]=arr;
}
else{                                   
aMap[key] = value;
}

Comment: @SyedAmberIqbal You're still wrapping your array inside itself once the key exists. Try using my code as a base for your tests, and your Map<String, List<String>> will work.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox for your answer. If you could add the comments what the code does, it would help js beginners like me to understand it in better way. Sharing a post I have found answering with the same way as mentioned here with comments. Hoping this would help someone: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020554/how-to-create-a-map-in-javascript-with-array-of-values-dynamically

Comment: @JigarTrivedi You're just in time. There's a new operator in town, `??=`, which makes it even easier to read, too.

Comment: @sfdcfox: great edit. This really helps a lot.